# Apche NiFi: Keeping multiple versions of a NAR

Tags: apache-nifi

Is it possible to keep multiple versions of NARs in lib folder?

I came across [this](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/NIFI-3380), which seems to suggest so.

What I want is to have my older flow templates keep working in newer versions of nifi(as some properties become invalid in newer versions). So I plan to copy NARs from previous nifi version in lib folder of my nifi installation.

Answer (score 1):

It *may* depend on the version of the NARs but in general yes you can have multiple versions of the same NAR in `nifi/lib`. Please note that (at the time of this writing) if you are trying to do a "rolling upgrade" of a NiFi cluster, there is a [known issue](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/NIFI-12016) with choosing the latest ("matching") NAR and you may end up with a "ghost" processor, the workaround is to select the correct available (and desired) version.

Comment: So I copied 1.10.0 NARs in lib folder of nifi 1.22.0 docker image, but I get error on container launch: 'java.lang.IllegalStateException: Multiple framework NARs discovered. Only one framework is permitted'.

Comment: Yes only one framework NAR is permitted, I would delete the older one and see if everything comes up ok